# Should i create a Class for each button in the interface?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a question, i watched a lot of tutorial about MVVM but i'm still confused.
I have an interface with more than one button on it, i have to implement the ICommand interface for bind the command to the View.

I did it like this:

MainSolution

```
Main Solution
    Model
        SomeClass.cs
    ViewModel
        Commands
            SomeCommands.cs
        SomeViewModel.cs
```

Ok, now in the interface i have more than one button, each one do separate things, example, one is for start a thread the other one for cancel it and a third one for another thing.
Should i create a separate class, that implement ICommand interface, for each button that i have on the View?

```
Main Solution
    Model
        SomeClass.cs
    ViewModel
        Commands
            StartCommands.cs
            CancelCommands.cs
            OtherCommands.cs
        SomeViewModel.cs
```

I'm asking this because when i implement the ICommand interface i have only one "Execute" method, and only one "CanExecute" method. What is the common way to implement multiple button on a View through binding?

I searched for example online without any luck... A lot of them are so confusing, and surely not for a newbie like me.

The other thing is when i have multiple View and Multiple ViewModel, should i create multiple Commands Folder for nesting it?

```
Main Solution
    Model
        SomeClass.cs
    ViewModel
        FirstCommands
            StartCommands.cs
            CancelCommands.cs
            OtherCommands.cs
        SecondCommands
            StartCommands.cs
            CancelCommands.cs
            OtherCommands.cs
        FirstViewModel.cs
        SecondViewModel.cs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO having a separate class for each command in a classic MVVM approach is an overkill. Use something like the MVVMLight's [RelayCommand](https://github.com/paulcbetts/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommand.cs) (and the [generic one](https://github.com/paulcbetts/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs) if you want to pass a parameter).

Then you can define your commands as your ViewModel members and provide `Execute`/`CanExecute` implementation as part of your ViewModel as well:

```
public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; }

public MyView()
{
    //[...]
    this.MyCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteMyCommand, this.CanExecuteMyCommand);
}

public void ExecuteMyCommand()
{
   //do work!
}

public bool CanExecuteMyCommand()
{
   //optional - control if command can be executed at a given time
}
```

And you can bind to `MyCommand` in XAML (assuming your View is bound to your ViewModel):

```
<Button Content='WORK!' Command='{Binding MyCommand}' />
```

Comment: Why the RelayCommand accept a "Type" too? (RelayCommand<T>), what you can do with that? A type of what?

Comment: Parameter. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064308/how-to-pass-command-parameter-to-method-in-viewmodel-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `DelegateCommand` class. You [can use Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.50).aspx), or just google around and steal one; [here's one on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788764/424129) that I haven't tested but it looks legit. If you don't need a parameter for a command, just ignore the `parameter` argument.

A `DelegateCommand` implements `ICommand`, and calls an `Action` or `Action<object>` that you pass to its constructor, like so (from the StackOverflow answer linked above):

```
public DelegateCommand AddFolderCommand { get; protected set; }
public MyViewModel(ExplorerViewModel explorer)
{           
    AddFolderCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAddFolderCommand, (x) => true);
}

public void ExecuteAddFolderCommand(object param)
{          
    MessageBox.Show("this will be executed on button click later");
}
```

This should have been included in WPF, but wasn't, for whatever reason.

Comment: @exSnake The only difference is the name. Tomato, tomahto. They do the same thing. Some people call it one, some call it the other. There's a lot of implementations out there which do the same thing under either name, or some other name.

Comment: @exSnake I like decPL's strongly typed generic parameter version, personally. But take your pick.